# gtsummary: controlling the number decimal places for each variable

Tags: r, gtsummary

I would like to perform granular control of the number of decimal places for all statistics of each variable. In the reproducible example below, let's say I want to have the mean and median of "age" displayed with one decimal place and the mean and median of "marker" with 3 decimal places. I have been unable to achieve that. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
library(gtsummary)
trial %>% select(trt, age, marker) %>% 
  tbl_summary(by = trt,
            missing = "no",
            type = all_continuous() ~ "continuous2",
            statistic = all_continuous() ~ c(
              "{mean}",
              "{median}"),
            digits = list(all_continuous() ~ c(1, 3)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the desired number of digits for each variable like so:

```
library(gtsummary)
trial %>% 
  select(trt, age, marker) %>% 
  tbl_summary(by = trt,
              missing = "no",
              type = all_continuous() ~ "continuous2",
              statistic = all_continuous() ~ c(
                "{mean}",
                "{median}"),
              digits = list(age ~ 1, marker ~ 3))
```

[image]